# how to keep duplicate of dom after empty in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to keep record of a DOM children after calling function `empty()` on it.

I tried below, but my duplicate turn out to be empty:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var root = document.getElementById('root');
  var rootDuplicate = root;
  $(root).empty();
  console.log(rootDuplicate.childNodes);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sgLub16d/21/

In above if you remove `$(root).empty();` line. `rootDuplicate` then contains the children.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `replaceWith` instead - that way, you can replace with an empty `<span id="root">` while keeping the reference to the old populated one:

```js
var root = document.getElementById('root');
var rootDuplicate = root;
$(root).replaceWith($('<span id="root" />'));
console.log(rootDuplicate.childNodes.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="root">some data<span id="child"> here</span></span>
```

Another method would be to save the `.childNodes` in an array first:

```js
const children = [...$('#root')[0].childNodes];
$('#root').empty();
console.log(children.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="root">some data<span id="child"> here</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cloneNode(deep)` method of `DOM` api to get the copy of the node for future reference .

Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (inline) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element properties (e.g., node.onclick = someFunction). Additionally, for a  element, the painted image is not copied.

> **Tip:** Use the appendChild() or insertBefore() method to insert the cloned node to the document.
>
> Tip: Set the deep parameter value to true if you want to clone all descendants (children), otherwise false.

**Parameter**

> `deep` Boolean Optional. Specifies whether all descendants of the node should be cloned. 
> `true`- Clone the node, its attributes, and its descendants.
> `false` - Default. Clone only the node and its attributes

**Warning**

> cloneNode() may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  let root = document.getElementById('root');
  let cln = root.cloneNode(true);
  $(root).empty();
  console.log(cln .childNodes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root">
 <span>Test</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer  is using jQuery [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

Basically, you will copy the element into a variable (`rootDuplicate`).

Notice that in the example below, `rootDuplicate` is a jQuery element. So I used `[0]` on it to console log the `.childnodes` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var root = $('#root');
  var rootDuplicate = root.clone();
  root.empty();
  console.log(rootDuplicate[0].childNodes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="root">some data<span id="child"> here</span></span>
```